# Text not centered perfectly in vertical direction, since the descendant of the font is slightly bigger

Tags: html, css, fonts, figma

When I tried out the [**Calibre**](https://en.bestfonts.pro/font/calibre) font on the web, I noticed the text was not centered in vertical direction properly. After researching I figured out that the descendant of the font is slightly thicker than the ascendant.

The below image is the calibre font in Figma which clearly shows that the descendant is bigger
[image]

As it was on figma it was easily corrected. But when I tried it out on the web, I faced the same problem. The text is not properly centering in the vertical direction.
[image]

[image]

I've attached the code here.

```
    <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: "calibre-semi-bold";
                src: url(./calibre-semibold-webfont.ttf);
            }
    
            .text {
                font-family: "calibre-semi-bold";
                font-size: 6em;
            }
    
            .container {
                background-color: orange;
                height: 120px;
                width: 70%;
                display: inline-flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                line-height: 90px;
            }
        </style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text">
            Cutting Edge technology
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

After some googling, I found that actually there's a property called [descent-override](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/descent-override) that can be used in **@font-face** which solves the problem. However, MDN mentioned that the property won't be supported on Safari and other older version browsers.

```
@font-face {
            font-family: "calibre-semi-bold";
            src: url(./calibre-semibold-webfont.ttf);
            descent-override: 17%;
        }
```

after using **descent-override**
[image]
The difference is very hard to notice in the image, but it's very significant on the live web.

Is there any proper way to center this text vertically without compromising on browser compatibility? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would add `line-height: 100%;` to the `.text` element, to set the line height to the same size as the font-size.

Apart from that you could add `position:relative` and use a `top: ...` setting (trial and error for the value) on that element to offset it vertically.

Comment: What if I have various font sizes across my site? Should I have to set offset for each font size?

Comment: vertically centered across the site? You can try to use em or rem units (very smal values, like 0.02em - again: trial and error)